# Remove top and bottom black borders from AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, dropdown, autocompletetextview

I'm experiencing a problem with the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown component.

As you can see from the image below, there are those black borders inside the popup that I cannot get rid of.

**Black borders:**

[image: Back borders]

I'm an Android noob, and I already tried basically everything with any success.

Below the code, I'm using.

**activity.xml:**

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:hint="Categoria"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_xlarge"
                        app:hintEnabled="true"
                        app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu">

                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                            android:dropDownSelector="@color/white"
                            android:id="@+id/private_place_dropdown"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:dropDownHeight="300dp"
                            android:inputType="none"
                            android:drawableTint="@color/white"
                            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                            android:editable="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/piumaBaseColor"
                            />

                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**dropdown_menu_popup_item.xml:**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/grey_extradark"
    android:text="test"/>
```

Can you please help me? Thank you a lot!

Comment: have you tried with `background="@null"`

Comment: Just tried but without any success. Tried to put it basically everywhere inside components i use.

Comment: Is that a spinner or dialog? Can you share XML of that?

Comment: It's a Dropdown Menu, I'm populating it programmatically and setting to the AutoComplete the dropdown_menu_popup_item.xml layout.
Everything has been done following Material.io specs.

Comment: if its possible upload your code to github repo and provide me the link I will check.

Comment: Did you find some solution?

Answer (score 6):

This dark lined are additional background from `PopupBackgroundView`. For fix the issue just use for background the same `surfaceColor` as you have in your theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ...
    <item name="colorSurface">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is the solution :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:elevation="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/dateFilterContainer"
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            app:endIconTint="#252E68"
      ==>>  app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp" 
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp" <<==
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="4dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="4dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="4dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="4dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          ...
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Just set 0dp to boxStrokeWidth.